# error: cannot find symbol com: amplifyframework.util.Immutable

Tags: android-studio-3.0, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I am attaching to AWS Amplify and using this link https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/start

But after adding all dependencies i am getting below error:

```
14:12:02.093 [ERROR] [system.err] /Users/kejriwal/AndroidStudioProjects/KaranKavach/app/src/main/java/com/amplifyframework/datastore/generated/model/AmplifyModelProvider.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
14:12:02.093 [ERROR] [system.err] import com.amplifyframework.util.Immutable;
14:12:02.093 [ERROR] [system.err]                                 ^
14:12:02.093 [ERROR] [system.err]   symbol:   class Immutable
14:12:02.093 [ERROR] [system.err]   location: package com.amplifyframework.util
```

I have tried any links like
https://github.com/immutables/immutables/issues/141
But none helped, please provide suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what kind of shi* it was, it wasted my 3 days.
But now issue is resolved.(I tried cleaning project, even it didn't work.)

I deleted generated file AmplifyModelProvider.java, and rebuild the project and issue got resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the guy who caused this problem. Sorry.

Sounds like your original generated code was from an old version of the Amplify CLI.

Around March, the Amplify Android library moved `com.amplifyframework.core.Immutable` to `com.amplifyframework.util.Immutable`. The change occurred for the 0.10.0 release of the Android library.

The CLI was [updated](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/pull/3540) around that time, to start generating the new import.

Amplify Android is at 1.0 now, which means interfaces are stable, and breaking changes like this are no longer allowed.

You can update your CLI with:

```
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli@latest
```